# schema extenstion in graph API

Tags: graph, azure-active-directory

I'm considering schema extension in graph API. As the following article, we can use two methods to extend schema.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview

**Open extensions:** A good way for developers to get started.

**Schema extensions:** A more versatile mechanism for developers who care about storing typed data, making their schema discoverable and shareable, being able to filter, and in the future, being able to perform input data validation and authorization.

Besides that, it seems that I can use Azure AD schema extension but I cannot figure out what is the deference between Azure AD directory schema extensions and Schema extensions.

**Azure AD directory schema extensions**:Azure AD supports a similar type of extension, known as directory schema extensions, on a few directoryObject resources.

If I use Schema extensions not Open extensions, it means to extend Azure AD directory schema?  or Graph has another area rather than Azure AD to extend?

Thanks
O.M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema extensions and Azure AD directory schema extensions mean the same one, they are just for the different way to use.

[image]
For Schema extensions, the doc explains the way that uses MS graph API to do this.

[image]

And for Azure AD directory schema extensions, it uses the Azure AD graph API.

[image]

About the difference for Azure AD GRAPH API and MS GRAPH API, please read [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/).